# Cuckoo dump a PE file from a memory dump?

Tags: forensics, memory, sandbox

Can Cuckoo extract PE files from a memory dump or record the import table of the running process? I need to record the import table in PE not the called/executed API from the process.

There is `Process-Dump` which is able to extract PE from memory, So can Cuckoo has a feature to do the same task?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Cuckoo can extract PE files from memory dumps. In addition, Cuckoo also has the capability to record the import table of a running process, as well as the called/executed API from the process. This can be done through the use of the Cuckoo Memory Dump module.

Comment: For extracting PE after taking `memory.dmp`? If yes, shall I use another app to extract from the memory dump?

Comment: Also, do you know which property/code is responsible for recording the import table? I have looked at the documentation and have yet to find it.